# npm install getting Cannot read property 'name' of null error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Not too sure what is causing this error as `npm install` works fine on other computers.

NPM and Node versions:

```
C:\Users\Work>npm -v
8.3.2

C:\Users\Work>node -v
v14.16.1
```

Here is my log file:

```
1045 timing metavuln:calculate:security-advisory:laravel-mix:BsF+UACSDcae51QqbAQxlxsAnxFUZFgrvDV6vu6cKmFKYbSYdVVZnALm0hmDv4dJ/hBksQh4SoHNXqfEVpN6eg== Completed in 4ms
1046 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
1046 verbose stack     at npa (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-package-arg\npa.js:25:18)
1046 verbose stack     at FetcherBase.get (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetcher.js:486:16)
1046 verbose stack     at Object.packument (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\index.js:18:30)
1046 verbose stack     at Calculator.[packument] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\metavuln-calculator\lib\index.js:105:22)
1046 verbose stack     at Calculator.[calculate] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\metavuln-calculator\lib\index.js:56:23)
1046 verbose stack     at Calculator.calculate (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\metavuln-calculator\lib\index.js:43:31)
1046 verbose stack     at Map.[init] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\audit-report.js:173:36)
1046 verbose stack     at async Map.run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\audit-report.js:108:7)
1047 verbose cwd D:\code\click-webplanner
1048 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
1049 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
1050 verbose node v14.16.1
1051 verbose npm  v7.20.3
1052 error Cannot read property 'name' of null
1053 verbose exit 1
```

And this is my composer file:

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.4.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
    "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
    "fibers": "^5.0.0",
    "less": "^3.9.0",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "sass": "^1.26.8",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "save": "^2.3.3",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.3",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.4",
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.0.2",
    "ajv": "^6.8.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "axios-cancel": "^0.2.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.0.0-alpha.27",
    "dayjs": "^1.8.28",
    "flatpickr": "^4.5.2",
    "highlight.js": "^10.1.2",
    "laravel-echo": "^1.5.3",
    "laravel-mix": "^5.0.4",
    "marked": "latest",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "npm": "^6.9.0",
    "postcss": "^7.0.35",
    "prismjs": "^1.23.0",
    "prosemirror-utils": "^0.6.7",
    "pusher-js": "^4.4.0",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.33.1",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.0.2",
    "tiptap": "^0.19.0",
    "tiptap-extensions": "^0.21.0",
    "vue-bulma-datepicker": "^1.3.6",
    "vue-fuse": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-select": "^3.1.0",
    "vue-select2": "^0.2.6",
    "vue-sidebar-menu": "^3.7.0",
    "vue2-editor": "^2.6.6",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.17.0",
    "vuetify": "^2.2.33",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.4.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: I have started to get the same error as you. Same `npa.js` throwing the TypeError. Based on what I see I assume you're using Laravel as well. Not sure what is going on because I didn't actually make any changes to my NPM packages.json. I am using node v16.13.0 and npm v8.1.0 so it doesn't seem to be related to versions

Comment: Hey, try removing npm from dependencies then 1. delete package-lock.json and node module folder 2. run npm install again.

Answer (score 5):

This error is occurring with the `npm` version that you are using: `v8.3.2` and the way that you passing the version of the module `"tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.0.2"`

If you remove this library will see that the error will stop to happen.

To solve this you can change the `tailwindcss` version to `^2.0.1-compat`:

```
"tailwindcss": "^2.0.1-compat"
```

Or upgrade or downgrade your npm version:

Try to downgrade your node.js and npm version for other `lts` version like the `lts/fermium` (node `v14.19.0`, npm `v6.14.16`) or upgrade to the stable version (node `v17.5.0`, npm `v8.4.1`)

Also, the recommended version for the npm with the node version `v14.16.1` is the is `6.14.12` and not `8.3.2` as we can see in the [releases table](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/).

When you change the npm version you  will need:

1. Delete the `node_modules` directory and `package-lock.json` file.
2. Reinstall the modules using `npm install`

Comment: This fixed my issue. Way too low as a search result. All I got was "clear cache" results.